# JAVA How to Loop Socket Variable

Tags: java, serversocket

Im creating a simple client server program in java.

What I want to do is iterate variable so I can shorten my code. Here it is.

```
             Socket b1 = ss.accept();
             Socket b2 = ss.accept();
             Socket b3 = ss.accept();
        if(b1.isConnected()){
             System.out.println("Player from " + (b1.getLocalAddress().toString().substring(1) + ":" + b1.getLocalPort() + " has joined."));
        }

        DataOutputStream b1o = new DataOutputStream(b1.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader b1i = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader (b1.getInputStream()));

        if(b2.isConnected()){
             System.out.println("Player from " + (b2.getLocalAddress().toString().substring(1) + ":" + b2.getLocalPort() + " has joined."));
        }

        DataOutputStream b2o = new DataOutputStream(b2.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader b2i = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader (b.getInputStream()));

        if(b3.isConnected()){
        System.out.println("Player from " + (b3.getLocalAddress().toString().substring(1) + ":" + b3.getLocalPort() + " has joined."));
        }

        DataOutputStream b3o = new DataOutputStream(b3.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader b3i = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader (b3.getInputStream()));
```

Is there any way to loop variable name so it goes b1 at first loop, then b2, so on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe start by having a look at [All About Sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) - You should have a "server" which "accepts" incoming connections inside a loop, when a new connection is established, you should spawn a new thread to handle communicating with that socket

Comment: Also if  you add "example" or "tutorial" to a web search you can often get good results.  Example I found this page, which seems to have some decent examples: https://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/spring05/cs450/sockets/socket.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MadProgrammer said, it is best to start a new thread on every connection, as `ss.accept()` blocks. You can try something like this:

```
Socket b;
ServerSocket ss;
ClientConnection newClient;
Thread newThread;

while(true) {
    try {
        b = ss.accept();

        System.out.println("Player from " + (b.getLocalAddress().toString().substring(1) + ":" + b.getLocalPort() + " has joined."));
        newClient = new ClientConnection(b);

        newThread = new Thread(newClient);
        newThread.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientConnection implements Runnable {

    //each connection should have its own socket and streams
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream outputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream inputStream;

    public ClientConnection(Socket socket) {
       this.socket = socket;
       this.outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
       this.inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do stuff with connection you have
    }
}
```

I would also recommend keeping an array of your connections so you don't lose them.

Answer (score 1):

Create an arrayList

```
ArrayList<Socket> socketList = new ArrayList();
socketList.add(ss.accept());
socketList.add(ss.accept());
socketList.add(ss.accept());
```

And then loop over the socketList

```
for(Socket socket : socketList){
  //Add your code here
 }
```